# Why is a set being compact equivalent to it being closed?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

The definition of compact in my book is

A set K is compact if every open cover of K has a finite subcover.

Take the set of all the points inside and on the unit circle (closed). Then any open cover bigger than the unit circle could have a finite subcover.

Similarly, couldn't the set of all the points inside the unit circle (open) follow similar logic? Any open cover of the circle (anything larger than the unit circle) could have a finite subcover

Comment: The term "circle" refers only to the boundary; the set of points "inside" the circle is called the "disk".

Comment: Take $S_r = \{x \mid |x| < r\}$  Then $\{S_r \mid 0<r<1\}$ is an open cover of the open disk with no finite subcover

Comment: The equivalence between closed and compact is true only in a compact space.

Comment: Note being compact and being closed are not equivalent.  Compactness implies closedness, but an unbounded closed set is not compact.  However, a famous theorem states that in any metric space, a set is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.

Comment: @aschepler what is the difference between closed and bounded? I tried to understand it but I'm still confused.

Comment: @saulspatz Isn't   {Sr∣0<r<1} a finite subcover of itself? Or does it not work that way.

Comment: $S_r$ is a set for every $0<r<1.$  Pick such an $r,$ say $r=.99.$  Now $S_r$ does not cover the open unit disk.  In particular it doesn't cover the point $(0,.999).$

Comment: @SteveK3223 No, because $\{S_r \mid 0<r<1\}$ is a collection of infinitely many open sets. A finite cover is a collection of finitely many open sets.

Comment: @SteveK3223 "Bounded" means that there's some number $D$ so that no matter what two points $x$ and $y$ in a set $S$ you choose, $d(x,y) < D$.  Or, "bounded" is equivalent to fitting inside some single sphere.  This is related to a definition of a set's diameter.  In $\mathbb{R}^2$, any line is unbounded: no matter what $D$ you choose, there are some points on the line farther than $D$ from each other.  Informally, you can think of "unbounded" as "going off to infinity".

Answer (score 3):

What about the open cover $\{U_{\alpha}\}$, where $U_{\alpha}$ is the open  circle centered at the origin of radius $\alpha$? There is no finite subcover of this that covers the open unit circle.

Comment: Isn't the set  {Uα} a finite subcover of itself?

Comment: The open cover is all sets of the form $U_{\alpha}$, where $0<\alpha<1$. There are infinitely many such $\alpha$.

Comment: why couldn't you say the same thing for a closed unit disk, and just make your example open subcover go from 0 < α < 1.1

Comment: No, since then the set $U_{1.05}$ itself would cover the closed unit circle.

Comment: The point is that in order to cover the closed unit circle, you would necessarily have to have an $\alpha$ larger than $1$. But then that set would cover the closed unit circle all by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following open cover of the interior of the unit circle.
$$ \mathscr{C} = \left\{ \ B( \mathbf{0}, r) \ \colon \ 0 < r < 1 \ \right\}, $$
where $B( \mathbf{0}, r)$ denotes the interior of the circle of radius $r$ centered at the origin.  Note that this cover has no finite sub-cover.

In a topological space, not every compact set is closed. For example, let $X = \{ a, b, c \}$ with the indiscrete topology. Then every subset of $X$ is compact, but no non-empty, proper subset of $X$ is closed.

In a Hausdorff topological space, every compact set is also closed. And, since every metric space is also a Hausdorff space (with respect to a metric topology), so this fact also holds in metric spaces.

However, not every closed set is compact. For example, the set of integers is closed but not compact in the set $\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers with the usual topology.

Answer (score 0):

In metric topology we need to have closed and bounded for compactness.

Also note that the definition of  compactness indicates that every open covering must have a finite subcovering.

Thus if you choose an open covering for your set with a finite subcovering, that does not make your set compact.